# Duplicating multiple rows in a database with changes and auto incrementing Ids

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-2

In short what I need to do is:

1. Duplicate X amount of rows in a table
2. Alter a few fields
3. Keep the auto incrementing IDs in order.

This is what I have going so far.

```
$this->db->query("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpTbl AS SELECT * FROM orders_products WHERE op_order_id = $id");
$temp = $this->getAll('tmpTbl');

## grab the highest id in the orders_products table so we can begin auto_inc after that
$this->db->select_max("op_id");
$max = $this->getAll('orders_products');
## set the id to a counter for the loop
$counter = $max[0]->op_id;

## loop through the results editing fields as needed
foreach ( $temp as $t ) :
  $counter++;
  $this->db->query("UPDATE tmpTbl SET op_id = $counter, op_order_id = $orderId WHERE op_order_id = $id");
endforeach;
$temp = $this->getAll('tmpTbl');

## insert the new duplications into the orders_products table
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO orders_products SELECT * FROM tmpTbl");

## drop the temp table so it is fresh and clean for the next duplication
$this->db->query("DROP TEMPORARY TABLE tmpTbl");
```

When I run it I get up to this line

```
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO orders_products SELECT * FROM tmpTbl");
```

and it throws me this error

```
Duplicate entry '54' for key 'PRIMARY

INSERT INTO orders_products SELECT * FROM tmpTbl
```

The reason I created the counter in the first place was to be a fix for this problem. However, I am sadly mistaken.

Comment: In this line `$this->db->query("UPDATE tmpTbl SET op_id = $counter, op_order_id = $orderId WHERE op_order_id = $id");`, where are values of `$orderID` and `$id` determined? Is `op_id` your primary key? Is all you are trying to do in your temp table is set `op_id` = `op_id` + `$counter`? Are you guaranteed that no other rows are added to the original table after you make a copy of it but before you try to insert temp table rows into it?

Comment: `$orderID` and `$id` are set prior to reaching this part of the code. I overlooked them when copying the code block into the question. They remain the same for this example. Yes, `op_id` is the primary key. No, `op_id` is not `op_id` = `op_id` + `$counter`. `$counter` is the last id in `order_products`+ 1. And yes, I can guarantee that no other rows are added to the original table after I make a copy of it but before I insert the temp table rows into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do In your case is to remove the ID col. from the SELECT so that the INSERT will generate automatically the ID.

```
INSERT INTO orders_products (column2,column3,etc)
    SELECT column2, column3, etc FROM tmpTbl
```

Comment: I used this as a starting point for the solution.

I didn't want to list out every column because I wasn't sure if there will be other columns added to the table as new features are added to the project. However, I am absolutely sure the name of the auto incrementing id field will never change. So I used `Describe` and looped through the field names removing the id and then setting it to a variable. Finally changing 

`$this->db->query("INSERT INTO orders_products SELECT * FROM tmpTbl");` 

to 

`$this->db->query("INSERT INTO orders_products ( $columns ) SELECT $columns FROM tmpTbl");`

Comment: I'm glad you could get it to work. Yes, if there are several columns, a good implementation would be to substract (or ignore) the ID col from a string or array.